# how to add string into JsonArray

Tags: android, json

I am trying to add string values in JsonArray and after that create Json String to send it on server.

I was searching on google but I couldn't find anything helpful. Could anyone tell me how to this?
Thanks

```
 JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
 list.put("Hello");
 list.put("Hey");
```

After that I want create JSONString

Comment: Can you post your code that you have been trying with?

Comment: According to docs it seems that you do it the right way: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#put(boolean). How do you check that it's not added?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simple:

```
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
list.put("Hello");
list.put("Hey");

String jsonString = list.toString()
```

according to docs it should result in "["Hello", "Hey"]"

Answer (score 1):

just use

`list.toString(2)`

this will give you the string in json

Comment: He wanted to add String, not to retrieve it

Comment: after using his code use list.toString to get the JSON-String