# Put String value in gson.JsonArray

Tags: java, json

I want to store a `String` in a `JsonArray`.
Ex:

```
"virtual_hosts": [ "some_host"]
```

How should I do this, with the help of java.

```
JsonArray arr = new JsonArray();
arr.add()
```

This only lets me add a `JsonObject`, but I want to store a `String`.

Comment: you may check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729598/how-to-add-a-string-array-in-a-json-object and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053332/how-to-add-string-into-jsonarray

Comment: *"How should I do this"* Use a JSON library. Search the web. There are multiple libraries available for Java. If you're asking how to use a specific library, you need to say which one you're trying to use.

Comment: You can create a list of hosts and set the property in JSON, please check the answer below.

Comment: You should mention that you want to use **gson**. The suggested links to possible duplicates are using another library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to use gson by google, looks like you **have to** do it this way:

```
JsonPrimitive firstHost = new JsonPrimitive("vlbr-vlbre9ef7a820b3f43c7bd3418bb62.uscom-central-1.c9dev1.oc9qadev.com");

JsonArray jArray = new JsonArray();
jArray.add(firstHost);

JsonObject jObj = new JsonObject();
jObj.add("virtual_hosts", jArray);
```

The first line converts your java string into a json string.

In the next two steps, a json array is created and your string is added to it.

After that, a json object which is going to hold the array is created and the array is added with a key that makes the array accessible.

If you inspect the object, it looks exactly like you want to have it.

There is no simple way in adding just a string to an `JsonArray` if you want to use *gson*. If you need to add your string directly, you probably have to use another library.

Comment: yes i am using JsonArray from google. But there is no class called JsonPrimitive. What is the other method to convert java string to Json string

Comment: @YashaJadwani actually there is one, I tested the code on my PC. Here you can see the gson api of [JsonPrimitive](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonPrimitive.html). Maybe you are using an older version of Java and/or gson?

Comment: thanks this help a lot!! its working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of hosts and set the property in JSON.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;    
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> hosts = new ArrayList<String>();
        hosts.add("vlbr-vlbre9ef7a820b3f43c7bd3418bb62.uscom-central-1.c9dev1.oc9qadev.com");
        hosts.add("dummy.oc9qadev.com");

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj.put("virtual_hosts", hosts);

        System.out.println("Final JSON String is--"+jsonObj.toString());


    }
}
```

> Output -
>
> {     "virtual_hosts":
>   ["vlbr-vlbre9ef7a820b3f43c7bd3418bb62.uscom-central-1.c9dev1.oc9qadev.com",
>   "dummy.oc9qadev.com"] }

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is storing a JSONArray into a JSONObject. Because the key `virtual_hosts` is going to contain a value as JSONArray.

Below code can help you.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    jsonArray.add( "vlbr-vlbre9ef7a820b3f43c7bd3418bb62.uscom-central-1.c9dev1.oc9qadev.com" );

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    jsonObject.put( "virtual_hosts", jsonArray );


    System.out.println( jsonObject );

}
```

**Output:**

```
{"virtual_hosts":["vlbr-vlbre9ef7a820b3f43c7bd3418bb62.uscom-central-1.c9dev1.oc9qadev.com"]}
```

Maven dependecny

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: They seem to be using the Gson library by google.